# Remove sensitive information from environment variables in postgres docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I want to make a postgres database image but don't want to expose password and username which are stored as environment variable when produced using docker-compose.yml file. Basically, I don't want anyone to exec into the container and find out the variables.

One way is to use docker-secrets, but I don't want to to use docker swarm because my containers would be running on a single host.

my docker-compose file -

```
    version: "3"
    services:
       db:
         image: postgres:10.0-alpine
      environment:
         POSTGRES_USER: 'user'
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'pass'
         POSTGRES_DB: 'db'
```

Things I have tried -

1) unset the environment variable at the end of entrypoint-entrypoint.sh

```
        for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
            case "$f" in
            *.sh)     echo "$0: running $f"; . "$f" ;;
            *.sql)    echo "$0: running $f"; "${psql[@]}" -f "$f"; echo ;;
            *.sql.gz) echo "$0: running $f"; gunzip -c "$f" | "${psql[@]}"; echo ;;
            *)        echo "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
            esac
            echo
        done
        unset POSTGRES_USER
```

nothing happened though. :(

2) init.sql inside docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, to create db, user and pass without using env.
I shared the volume, as -

````
```
   volumes:
       - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```
````

and, on my host, inside docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, I saved an init.sql as -

```
CREATE DATABASE docker_db;CREATE USER docker_user with encrypted password 'pass';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE docker_db TO docker_user;
```

I moved inside the running container and this file was there but, no user or database was created as mentioned in the file.

I have been stuck on this for past two days, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you set ENV in docker-compose it will contain the ENV, just try to run `docker exec -it db bash -c "printenv"` , while the unset work as expected.

Comment: @Adiii , is there a way to create db and user other than specifying in the environment? Please read my entire question.

Comment: If the user can execute into the container, then the secrets, exposed to the container, will be accessible as files. So that solution is not entirely secure in that regard either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any other env variable, you can check @LinPy's answer. It smartly uses Docker Image Build-time Variables to override the values. But at least, I was unable to benefit in this case maybe because these were some "special" variables of postgres and was not able to override them(any explanation is welcome in the comment section).

So, now coming to the solution -

Problem - Don't want postgres' username/password to be visible as environment variable.

Solution - Don't specify them is compose's environment variable section.

Instead, make user/database using a script. Postgres' image runs an entrylevel script, which in turn looks for any .sh/.sql file in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory and run it.

Example,

directory structure -

```
-docker-compose.yml
-docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  -init.sql
```

My docker-compose file -

```
version: "3"

services:
    db:
      image: postgres:10.0-alpine
      ports:
        - 8765:5432
      volumes:
        - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

init.sql file

```
CREATE DATABASE docker_db;CREATE USER docker_user with encrypted password 'pass';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE docker_db TO docker_user;
```

```
docker-compose up
docker exec -it container-id bash
psql -U docker_user docker_db
psql (10.0)
Type "help" for help.

docker_db=>
```

Now, delete init.sql from your host, as it is shared volume, it will also be deleted from your container.

Answer (score 10):

use args without values to build the image in your `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG PASSWORD
```

and build it using

```
export PASSWORD="MYPASS" && docker build ...
```

in this way the `ARG` is not there when running the `container`

here is a complete example:

`dockerfile`:

```
FROM postgres:10.0-alpine

ARG my_user
ARG my_pass
```

`Compose`:

```
version: "3"
services:
       db:
         build:
           context: .
           args:
            - my_user
            - my_pass       
         environment:
           - POSTGRES_USER=${my_user}
           - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${my_pass}
           - POSTGRES_DB=db
```

run it:

```
export my_user=test && export my_pass=test1cd && docker-compose up -d --build
```

now if you login to the `container` and try `echo $my_pass` you get an empty string

result :

```
docker exec -ti 3b631d907153 bash

bash-4.3# psql -U test db
psql (10.0)
Type "help" for help.

db=#
```

Comment: WARNING: The my_user variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The my_pass variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.db.environment contains {"POSTGRES_USER": ""}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string @LinPy

Comment: I just copy pasted your code in Dockerfile, compose file and run using your command.

Comment: The container is running fine(environment variable is updated to empty string) but the user is not created inside postgres. @LinPy

Comment: try to connect to the DB using your username/pasword wich you use with export, it should works, `docker exec -it db psql -U USER db`

Comment: psql: FATAL:  role "test" does not exist
```docker exec -it container_id psql -U test``` @LinPy I've used same user and pass as mentioned in you answer.

Comment: see the update you need to specify the db at the end of the command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199617/discussion-between-shirish-and-linpy).

Comment: I tried to do the same, I could still see - POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD, POSTGRES_DB in the container environment. However for any other env variable other than these 3, its working fine.. any idea @LinPy?

Comment: I declared another environmebt variable in docker-compose.yml file using the same syntax. 
I could see an empty sttring for that variables value from inside the container

But for these 3 vars, i still see the values that ere passed. 
 What happens when you do this?
`docker exec -ti 3b631d907153 printenv`

Comment: this is what i got 

`KARAN=
POSTGRES_USER=testw
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test1cdqq
POSTGRES_DB=db1
`   (KARAN was my custom env variable)

Comment: @LinPy is there something to do with docker-compose version? Because, I updated my version now to -> ```docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896```
and now, environment variables are not updating to empty strings, as mentioned by @KaranRaina

Comment: I used `docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b` and working fine with me, sorry I can not help you more

Answer (score 9):

### **update**

Before using docker secrets in Compose, take into consideration this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257319/secrets-in-docker-compose) and that [github answer](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40046#issuecomment-538777305).

---

You can use [docker secrets in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#use-secrets-in-compose).

As stated in the relevant section of the [docker postgresql docs](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/content.md#docker-secrets):

> As an alternative to passing sensitive information via environment
>   variables, `_FILE` may be appended to some of the previously listed
>   environment variables, causing the initialization script to load the
>   values for those variables from files present in the container. In
>   particular, this can be used to load passwords from Docker secrets
>   stored in `/run/secrets/<secret_name>` files.

Therefore your compose file can read:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.0-alpine
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER_FILE: /run/secrets/user
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/pass
    POSTGRES_DB_FILE: /run/secrets/db
  secrets:
    - user
    - pass
    - db

secrets:
  user:
    file: user.txt
  pass:
    file: pass.txt
  db: 
    file: db.txt
```

Comment: Aren't files in `/run/secrets` deleted if the image is re-built ?

Comment: @Florent I do not use secrets any more. Nevertheless I imagine that those files could be copied using a Dockerfile. The example above is somehow over simplified.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want anyone to exec into the container and find out the variables.

This isn't realistic and I wouldn't worry about it.

The fundamental problem here is that Docker doesn't especially have any access controls over which `docker` commands someone can run.  **If you can run any `docker` command at all then you have unrestricted root-level access to the host.**  For instance, you can

```
docker run --rm -it -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/sudoers
docker exec -it myapp_db env
docker inspect myapp_dbadmin
docker exec -it myapp_app cat ./db_config.yml
docker run --rm -it -v /:/host busybox cat /host/$PWD/db_config.yml
```

The easiest thing to do here would be to not let any users you don't trust have access to the system at all.  (If you're in a cloud environment, two cloud instances of half the size generally have the same cost as one bigger instance, so partitioning users this way could be straightforward.)

In theory you could limit things by making sure `docker` access is restricted (for instance, behind `sudo`), passing credentials only in files, and making sure the corresponding host files also have appropriate file permissions so they can't be read.  That generally involves moving this configuration out of the `docker-compose.yml` file.  It's not a "usual" Docker configuration but it does address the problem that environment variables aren't really that secure.

Answer (score 0):

You have this way described on the Postgres page of DockerHub.

"Docker Secrets

As an alternative to passing sensitive information via environment variables, _FILE may be appended to some of the previously listed environment variables, causing the initialization script to load the values for those variables from files present in the container. In particular, this can be used to load passwords from Docker secrets stored in /run/secrets/<secret_name> files. For example:

```
$ docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/postgres-passwd -d postgres
```

Currently, this is only supported for POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS, POSTGRES_PASSWORD, POSTGRES_USER, and POSTGRES_DB."

What can be seen when inspecting the service:
[image]