# Secrets in docker compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

My environment is an ubuntu 18.04 VPS.

I can't get file-based secrets to work with mariadb in a docker container.

1. create `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4.8-bionic
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/password_root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/password_user
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
    secrets:
      - password_root
      - password_user
secrets:
  password_root:
    file: .secret_password_root
  password_user:
    file: .secret_password_user
```

2. create secrets:

```
echo -n secret > .secret_password_root
echo -n secret > .secret_password_user
chown root:root .secret_password*
chmod 400 .secret_password*
```

(Note that I can set 444, but that would expose the secrets file on the host which is a very bad idea.)

3. run:

```
docker-compose up
```

Error:

> db_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 37: /run/secrets/password_root: Permission denied

According to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-2), the secrets file should be mounted as `0444`, but that's obviously not happening.

Comment: It says `/run/secrets/db_password_root` in error message, but your compose doesn't have this file in secrets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently [this is not supported](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40046#issuecomment-538777305) for "docker compose", only for "docker swarm". The docs are misleading.

> Docker Compose doesn't support real (swarmkit) secrets, and imitates them by bind-mounting the file directly into the container (which means that permissions on the host are the same as in the container).
>
> You can change the ownership of the file on the host to match the uid/gid of the user in the container, but otherwise I don't think there's much that can be done unfortunately

#### UPDATE 2023

If you want this functionality, **please upvote [this feature request](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/45642) on the repo**, and/or add your opinions, so the developers know how badly we need this feature. Thank you.

Comment: That stinks, I've been trying to get this to work and hitting your comment explains why it doesn't. Any good suggestions on hiding a token using docker-compose and Dockerfile during the build process? I don't want the token committed by accident by anyone. Thanks!

Comment: @nyhunter77 I suppose you could use an `.env` file?

Comment: You'd think so @lonix, as did i, but i need the values during build, not run. Figured it out last night. I actually set a default arg in the Dockerfile, that way the real one doesn't get committed into git, then when i run docker-compose, i run: docker-compose build --build-arg JOB_TOKEN=<the real token> and that seems to fit the needs for now! Been trying to come up with a decent solution for over a day. :)

Comment: @nyhunter77 https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information

Comment: Interesting [alternative](https://serverfault.com/a/1116325/473183).

Answer (score 4):

Since [docker-compose v2.5.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.5.0) this is now possible.

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret,target=/root/mysecret cat /root/mysecret
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  my-app:
    build:
      context: .
      secrets:
        - mysecret

secrets:
  mysecret:
   file: ~/.npmrc
```

Shell:

```
$ docker-compose build
```

Comment: Can this be done in the normal way, without a build - as shown in the OP?

Comment: yes, if you mean the *up* command. E.g. `docker-compose --build up`

Comment: No I mean without a build, as shown in the OP. In your code it has `build:` section so it's building a new image - do you know whether it can be done without building an image?

Comment: the `secrets:` section in `build:` is needed. See in code: https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/9386/files#diff-892466cfaee03eb856c2aa2b468059a44cc6f2df1649136f724b387f1e9ab1c2R260

Comment: Thanks. Did some investigation. This is for "build time" secrets, rather than "runtime secrets". See [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/43543#issuecomment-1231805089). It's the traditional runtime/mounting secrets that I was interested in; I suspect that's true for many (/most?) others (7k views so far). But I think this will be very useful to some people, thanks for adding this answer.

Answer (score -3):

The tip point is here:

```sh
chown root:root .secret_password* # set root as owner
chown 400 .secret_password*       # set `400` as owner
```

Replace `chown` with `chmod:

```sh
chown root:root .secret_password*
chmod 400 .secret_password*
```

Comment: Good catch... that was a typo, but it doesn't change the problem unfortunately :(